# Converting escaped UTF-16 (JSON entities) back to normal UTF-8 inside MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf-16

How do I convert data like that

```
\u0441\u043e\u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u0435\u043d
```

back to normal UTF8 inside MySQL? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert between charsets in mysql by reading the data as binary and convert it to a target charset, like this (if you have a table called `example` and a column called `data`:

```
UPDATE `example` SET data=CONVERT(CONVERT(`data` USING binary) USING utf8);
```

The JSON \uXXXX entities are in hexadecimal UTF-16 encoding, so if you have a mysql version with utf-16 support, you can convert them to utf-8. The function below shows you how to do it. First, you unhex() those values and then convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8:

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE FUNCTION Unjson (instring TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8)
RETURNS TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8
BEGIN

  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE utfstr TEXT CHARACTER SET utf16 DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE outstring TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT "";

  WHILE i < CHAR_LENGTH(instring) DO
    SET i = i + 1;
    SET c = SUBSTRING(instring, i, 1);
    IF c = "\\" THEN
      SET c = SUBSTRING(instring, i + 1, 1);
      IF c = "u" THEN
        SET utfstr = CONCAT(utfstr, UNHEX(SUBSTRING(instring, i + 2, 4)));
        SET i = i + 5;
      END IF;
    ELSE
      IF utfstr != "" THEN
        SET outstring = CONCAT(outstring, CONVERT(utfstr USING utf8));
        SET utfstr = "";
      END IF;
      SET outstring = CONCAT(outstring, c);
    END IF;
  END WHILE;
  IF utfstr != "" THEN
    SET outstring = CONCAT(outstring, CONVERT(utfstr USING utf8));
  END IF;

  RETURN outstring;
END@@
DELIMITER ;
```

With this MySQL function in place, you can convert your tables with:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `column_name`=Unjson(`column_name`);
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5, but I don't think 5.0 has utf-16 support, so you might have to check your MySQL version...

(And yeah, I recommend you to make a backup before running this in your production environment...) ;)

Comment: nah, it is php's json_encode that recklessly escaped all the data in Russian and other languages. JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE has just been introduced in 5.4 and I am trying to find the easier way to convert all the data back to normal.

Comment: That is utf-16 which you have to unhex() first. I edited my answer with an example on how to do it in MySQL.